# Zoom in / Zoom out tkinter text box problem

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, import, zooming

I've made a zoom in/out function for my tkinter text box .... The issue comes up when I import "manual_data_input_editor() " into other file and when I call the function into that file nothing happens ... but when I call the function in the same python file it works perfectly fine. So , what's the problem ?

```html
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

count = 14
s_aux = 14
def manual_data_input_editor() :

 def data_to_plot():
     return txt_edit.get(1.0, "end-1c")

 global k
 k = 0
 def number_of_clicks():
     global k
     k += 1

 def change_theme():
    global k
    if k % 2 == 1 :
        txt_edit.configure(background='#202e50' , foreground="#d7cc25" , insertbackground="#d7cc25")
        txt_edit.config(cursor="xterm #fdbb2d")
    else :
        txt_edit.configure(background='#d6e7e4' , foreground="#85138c" , insertbackground="#85138c")
        txt_edit.config(cursor="xterm #fdbb2d")

 def combine_funcs(*funcs):
       def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
       return combined_func

 
 window = tk.Tk()
 window.iconbitmap("chart.ico")
 window.state("zoomed")
 window.title("Input Chart Data Editor")
 window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=800, weight=1)
 window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=800, weight=1)

 txt_edit = tk.Text(window , state=tk.NORMAL)
 txt_edit.configure(background='#d6e7e4' , foreground="#85138c" , insertbackground="#85138c" )
  
 global count
 def mouse_wheel(event):
    global count
    if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
        count -= 1
    if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
        count += 1
    font = Font(size=count)
    txt_edit.configure(font=font)
 window.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)
 
 global s_aux
 def zoom_in_function():
      global s_aux
      s_aux += 1
      txt_edit.configure(font = Font(size = s_aux))
      print(s_aux)

 def zoom_out_function():
      global s_aux
      s_aux -= 1
      txt_edit.configure(font = Font(size = s_aux))

 def clear_textbox():
      txt_edit.delete(1.0 , END)
 

 window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could it be that the other program that imports this also creates an instance of `Tk`? You need to show us how you're importing and using this file. Also, are you sure _this_ code reproduces the problem? When I run this code I get a blank window.

Comment: Also, are you aware you can use a single `Font` object and just change it's size, rather than constantly creating new `Font` objects?

Comment: I got blank window when `manual_data_input_editor()` is executed inside same file or in other script (after importing the function) because you forget to call any layout function on `txt_edit`.  It works fine after doing that.